# How to open password protected PDF using MuPDF

Tags: java, android, pdf, mupdf

I want to open password protected PDF files using [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) but I don't know if MuPDF provides any convenient method to do so. I am showing the simple PDFs as following and it is working fine:

```
File file = [PATH TO THE FILE];

if (file.exists()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tried to search for it on Google but I could not find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this by customizing the `MuPDFActivity.java` class.

While reading the code in `onCreate` method i came to know that it is has condition which checks that whether it needs password or not as:

```
if (core != null && core.needsPassword()) {
```

and then it shows dialog withe EditText to input the password. Then password is verified via the function.

```
core.authenticatePassword(mPassword)
```

I sent the password of the file as String extra to MuPDFActivity class and remove passed it directly to the function.

```
if (core != null && core.needsPassword()) {
   if (core.authenticatePassword(mPassword)) {
      createUI(savedInstanceState);
   } else {
      requestPassword(savedInstanceState);
   }
   return;
}
```

You can ask me for complete code if anyone will need help.

Thanks.

Comment: how can you retrieve password?

Comment: Sorry could not understand what you want exactly, in my case i am getting password from the Server side and i use that to open the password protected PDF file.

Comment: i don't know th epassword.. and i want to ask to user. what should i do then?

Comment: You need to show dialog to the users so that they can enter the password, and then you can use that password to open the PDF.

Comment: where should i enter?

Answer (score 0):

To open a password protected pdf with mupdf you need to provide the password through the terminal like this:

```
mudpf -p DOCUMENT_PASSWORD filename.pdf
```